# Visual Studio 2013 installation freezes after some minutes

Tags: installation, freeze

[image]

And this situation occurs all the time. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you can give some information concerning your system?

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing. My ISO file was corrupted.